# Display minimum advertised price and retail pricing on product page magento2

Tags: magento2.4, product-page, advanced-pricing, msrp

Is it possible to display Minimum Advertised Price and retail pricing on product details page?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes, it is possible to display on the product detail page. You have to create a new container or block using catalog_product_view.xml in your custom module. After creating a PHP class you have to get data MSRP and Retail price using product attribute

Answer (score 0):

Create in your custom module

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.options.wrapper.bottom">
            <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.customattribute" template="Vendor_Module::product/view.phtml" before="product.info.addtocart"/>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Next you need to create

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/Product/View.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Product;

use Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context;
use Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct;

class View extends AbstractProduct
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->registry = $registry;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getCurrentProduct()
    {
        return $this->registry->registry('current_product');
    }

    public function getMsrp()
    {
        $msrp = $this->getCurrentProduct()->getData('msrp');
        return $msrp;
    }

    public function getRetailPricing()
    {
        $retailPrice = $this->getCurrentProduct()->getData('retail_pricing');
        return $retailPrice;
    }
}
```

Last create phtml file

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/product/view.phtml

```
<?php
/** @var \Vendor\Module\Block\Product\View $block */

$msrp = $block->getMsrp();
$retailPricing = $block->getRetailPricing();
?>

<?php if ($msrp != NULL): ?>
    <h2>Minimum Advertised Price: <?= $msrp ?></h2>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if ($retailPricing != NULL): ?>
    <h2>Retail Pricing: <?= $retailPricing ?></h2>
<?php endif; ?>
```